# Add environment variable to .bashrc through script

Tags: scripts, bashrc

I need to add the following lines to the end of .bashrc file in Ubuntu. How can I add these lines automatically using a script. If I run the script, then it automatically inserts the lines at the end of .bashrc file.

```
export APP="/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps"
export TOS="/opt/tinyos-2.x/tos"
```

Comment: @deenaik post your edit as new question. Do not hijack existing, answered questions.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use the echo command to append lines to the .bashrc script

So in your script use these lines

```
echo 'export APP=/opt/tinyos-2.x/apps' >> ~/.bashrc 

echo  'export TOS=/opt/tinyos-2.x/tos' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Make sure to use >> (append), if you use a single > you will overwrite the file.

`~/.bashrc` indicates `.bashrc` is in your home directory

Comment: When I do this it appends the echoed string to the last line already in the bashrc file; as in, not on a new line and without a space on the current last line...

Comment: @d8aninja, this would happen if the last line of your file was not terminated with [EOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character (`0x0A`).

Comment: What if we want to remove or update a variable from that file?

Answer (score 4):

Just an addition to above answers. If someone wants to export variables they can also use the below format. Hope it helps. =)

```
echo 'export PATH="${HOME}/soft:${PATH}"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more flexible way to achieve the desired:

**Insert or update** environment variable export

```sh
rcFile="~/.bashrc"

prop="WAYLAND_DISPLAY"   # export property to insert
val="wayland-1"          # the desired value

if grep -q "^export $prop=" "$rcFile"; then
  sed -i "s/^export $prop=.*$/export $prop=$val/" "$rcFile" &&
  echo "[updated] export $prop=$val"
else
  echo -e "export $prop=$val" >> "$rcFile"
  echo "[inserted] export $prop=$val"
fi
```

**Delete** environment variable export

```sh
rcFile="~/.bashrc"

prop="POSTGRE_PORT"    # export property to delete

if grep -q "^export $prop=" "$rcFile"; then
  sed -i "/^export $prop=.*$/d" "$rcFile" &&
  echo "[deleted] export $prop"
else
  echo "[not found] export $prop"
fi
```

For an implementation idea see: [gh.sh](https://github.com/rokobuljan/gh.sh)